# Modifying UIView frame more easily?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, cgrectmake

Often I need to simply move the view 5 pixels down.
My approach is like this

> ```
> view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,
>                         view.frame.origin.y + 5,
>                         view.frame.size.width,
>                         view.frame.size.height);
> ```

Isn't there some easier way? :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I should write a bunch of categories for the UIView class.

Something like

> ```
> -(void)changeFrameOriginHorizontally:(NSInteger)paramHorizontalChange
>                           vertically:(NSInteger)paramVerticalChange;
>
> -(void)changeFrameSizeHorizontally:(NSInteger)paramHorizontalChange
>                         vertically:(NSinteger)paramVerticalChange;
> ```

The main reason I do not like the solution in my original post is that it is very code sense unfriendly and too verbose.

I would allow for negative and positive values and nil for no change.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Your solution looks to swap code (non)sense for code smell... you are hiding that you are doing a frame manipulation (if that is what you would put behind those categories). As I already commented, frame.origin calcs are not supported by Apple if your view is subject to a transform.

Comment: Heh..I forgot to pass the reference to the view :)

Comment: No reference needed if its a category on UIView

Comment: Ah..true..I would call it on the view itself.

Comment: Isn't the category's name explicitly saying what will happen? How is that hiding?

Comment: Perhaps I should add that the implementation will generate a new frame and set it at once, not manipulate any of frame's properties selectively.

Comment: your category doesn't say HOW it will achieve the effect (I know, that's the point of a category, but I would _want_ to know whether you are accessing frame data at an inappropriate moment, or not) [edit - sorry, in haste i didnt _read_ the name of your category! still not convinced though]

Comment: Using these categories for 3 months now, I couldn't be hapier. I saved a ton of time and did code more comfortably. I will never get back to old way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

another solution

```
view.frame = CGRectOffset( view.frame, 0, 5 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a macro on [github](https://github.com/claybridges/libvarobjc) that will let you do it like

```
@morph(view.frame, _.origin.y += 5);
```

Or if you wanted to change `y` *and* `height`

```
@morph(view.frame, {
    _.origin.y += 5;
    _.size.height -= 5;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly better:

```
view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x, view.center.y+5);
```

Comment: Does this preserve those internal recalculations that are done when setting a frame? They are the reason only frame as a whole is changeable and not frame's properties..

Comment: Try it and see! Changing the center will affect the frame.origin but won't change the frame.size. Often it is safer (if you apply transforms to a view, frame origin becomes unreliable, and you are advised to use center and bounds instead).

Comment: @Earl, what do you mean by 'internal recalculations'?

Comment: You should be careful with just setting one view's center based on another as it may cause the resulting frame to not be on a pixel boundary and cause some hairy rendering

Comment: Any time you apply a transform you are going to have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have macro's for these:

```
#define VIEW_INCREASE_Y(view, value) view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,view.frame.origin.y+value,view.frame.size.width,view.frame.size.height)
```

Then you can do:

```
VIEW_INCREASE_Y(customView, 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the category route you should give it a prefix to avoid method name collisions.

e.g.

```
- (void)ps_addOffset:(CGPoint)offset;
{
    self.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectOffset(self.frame, offset.x, offset.y));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Macros:

```
#define width(a) a.frame.size.width
#define height(a) a.frame.size.height
#define top(a) a.frame.origin.y
#define left(a) a.frame.origin.x
#define bottom(a) top(a)+height(a)
#define right(a) left(a)+width(a)

#define FrameReposition(a,top,left) a.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width(a), height(a))
```

.....

```
FrameReposition(myView,0,0);
```